# Borel-Cantelli problem: Prove sum of probabilities is finite

Tags: law-of-large-numbers, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am looking for good solutions to this problem. Could you please help me with this? Any solution would be appreciated.

Let $\mathit{X_n}$ be independent random variables. Show that if $\mathit{X_n}$ converges almost surely, then for any $\epsilon > 0$:

$$\sum_{n\ge1} \mathit{P}(|\mathit{X_n} - \mathit{X_{n+1}}| > \epsilon) < \infty$$

Comment: If you are considering convergence to a particular constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ then you can say $|X_n-X_{n+1}|\leq |X_n-c| + |c-X_{n+1}|$. This is useful because the random variables in the sequence $\{|X_n-c|\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are mutually independent.

Comment: Alternatively you can take things in pairs: First consider $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P[|X_{2k+1}-X_{2k}|>\epsilon]$$ which is useful because now the terms involve mutually independent random variables.

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail since I did not catch your point?

Comment: The point of both comments is that we want to have a sequence of independent events in order to apply Borel-Cantelli.  The sequence $\{\{|X_n-X_{n+1}|>\epsilon\}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not have the required independence. We must do something about that.

Comment: I get it. Thank you for your explanation!